# What pop culture reference is Jessica Jones making?

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, the-defenders

In "Fish in the Jailhouse" (*Marvel's The Defenders*, S01E07), there is a scene involving Luke Cage, Jessica Jones and Matt Murdock (aka Daredevil), in which Matt notices someone is near, and I think **Jessica makes a pop culture reference**.

> LUKE: What's wrong?
>
> DAREDEVIL: We're not alone.
>
> JESSICA: (SIGHS) **MJ deep cut.**
> <sub>—"Fish in the Jailhouse" (*Marvel's The Defenders*, S01E07)</sub>

According to sources online, a "deep cut" refers to a **song** or a **track**, traditionally in an album or record, and it is "deep", figuratively, because it is hidden "deep" within the album, or otherwise in a hard to find source, making it a fringe, obscure or rare find that only a fan would know about.

> Deep Cut
> Typically refers to a more obscure or less accessible song in an artist's portfolio, one that only dedicated fans are aware of.
>
> Also increasingly used to refer to any obscure or less accessible artwork, opinion, trivia, etc.
> *"Bryan Cranston used to eat McDonald's every day on the set of Breaking Bad." "That's a deep cut, man. Where'd you learn that?"*
>
> <sub>—machinewater, ["Deep Cut"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/author.php?author=machinewater), Urban Dictionary</sub>

This term has also been used to apply to obscure art, opinions and trivia, etc. meaning that it can be summarised to mean `obscure reference`. From this, I gather that Jessica Jones is making a pop culture reference, or at least reacting to Daredevil's line and jokingly pretending he made a reference with his line, "We're not alone"..

### What pop culture reference is she making?

Answer (score 5):

### It is a reference to a song by Michael Jackson (aka **MJ**) titled "You Are Not Alone"

> That **you are not alone**
>   For I am here with you
>   Though you're far away
>   I am here to stay
>   <sub>—"You Are Not Alone" (Lyrics), Michael Jackson (written by R. Kelly)</sub>

**MJ** is a reference to Michael Jackson whose initials are M.J. He is often referred to that way, especially by fans.

Jessica Jones is reacting to Daredevil's line "We're not alone" and jokingly pretending he made a reference to a Michael Jackson song.

This is confirmed by the subtitles in foreign languages (e.g. Spanish), in which the line Jessica Jones says is:

> JESSICA: Como canta **Michael Jackson**.

Which translates to, "Just like the way Michael Jackson sings it". Since the subtitles are official, it's a surefire official confirmation that Michael Jackson (and one of his songs) is being referenced.